# Twilio 'Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT'

Tags: php, twilio, http-status-code-403, twilio-php

I'm having some trouble running a simple Twilio code.
This is my code:`

```
<?php include "twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php"; 
$sid = 'AC***'; 
$token = '[token]'; 
$version= '2010-04-01';
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);
$client->account->calls->create('+390550620591', '+393386432173','http://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/');
?>
```

It gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT' in /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php:119
Stack trace: 
#0 /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php(183): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('post', Array)
#1 /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php(183): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->post('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array, 'To=%2B393386432...')
#2 /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(92): Base_Services_Twilio->createData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array)
#3 /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/Rest/Calls.php(32): Services_Twilio_ListResource->_create(Array)
#4 /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/index.php(20): Services_Twilio_Rest_Calls->create('+390550620591', '+393386432173', 'http://demo.twi...')
#5 {main} thrown in /membri/testtwilio/MakeCall/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php on line 119
```

I'm using altervista for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your altervista control panel >> edit PHP settings >>

Then you need to verify your account by sending an sms or you won't be able to connect to the twilio api.. Fix that and everything should be good to go..

Comment: This must be set as the answer. It works.